# usage of React.memo() inside components with prop functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, memoization, react-functional-component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'

const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState<number>(0);
  const [otherCount, setOtherCount] = useState<number>(0);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount((pre) => {
      return pre + 1
    })
  }

  const decrease = () => {
    setOtherCount((pre) => {
      return pre - 1
    })
  }
  return (
    <>
      <DecrementComponent decrease={decrease} />
      <br />
      <br />
      <IncrementComponent increment={increment} />
    </>
  )
}

const DecrementComponent = React.memo(({ decrease }: { decrease: () => void; }) => {
  console.log("DecrementComponent");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={decrease}>Decrement</button>
    </div>
  )
})

const IncrementComponent = React.memo(({ increment }: { increment: () => void; }) => {
  console.log("IncrementComponent");
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increment}>Increment</button>
    </div>
  )
})

export default App
```

Although I used `React.memo()`, when I clicked increment or decrement functions, two components were rendered.
But I think one component should be rendered in this scenario.

Why were two component rendered ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`React.memo` can only help if the props don't change. But the `increment` and `decrement` functions change on every render, so the props are always changing. You will need to memoize those functions so that they don't change.

```
const increment = useCallback(() => {
  setCount((pre) => {
    return pre + 1
  });
}, []);

const decrement = useCallback(() => {
  setCount((pre) => {
    return pre - 1
  });
}, []);
```

Comment: Ideally they should have `setCount` as a dependency

Comment: @Bergi `useState` setters are stable refs, so i don't think they should change? indeed, i don't think react will show a warning for this (but could be wrong)

Comment: Yes, setters are stable so the code works, and the *react-hooks/exhaustive-deps* eslint plugin won't complain about them, but I think it's still a general best practice to specify them [like all other functions](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-it-safe-to-omit-functions-from-the-list-of-dependencies).